# Shaded smooth faces have weird shading

Tags: shadows

Why do shaded smooth faces have weird shading. Face orientation is as it should be I did check that.

[image: 4 faces have really weird shading that sticks out from the rest]

[image]

Comment: check if you have custom split normals in the data properties panel

Comment: Hello please share your object: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Here is the link to my object [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=vVQLn8W7" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/vVQLn8W7/)

Comment: Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Answer (score 1):

You have several duplicate vertices on your model. In <kbd>Edit</kbd> mode. hit <kbd>A</kbd> to select All then  <kbd>M</kbd> > <kbd>Merge by Distance</kbd>.

[image]

You'll briefly see a message in the bottom status bar saying that 16 vertices have been removed and your topology will then be correct.

[image]

Comment: Incidentally, you also have overlapping topology around the crotch area which probably happened before you applied a mirror modifier and also round the shoulders where the arms and the body overlap. You can see this in wireframe mode (Shift-Z).

Comment: Thanks man, worked like a charm, and yes thank you for pointing out the crotch area, I didn´t put clipping in the mirror modifier. That being said, I have been looking at this overlap in the arm and shoulders you mentioned and can´t see it at all, even in wireframe mode and looking inside the model. If it doesn't trouble you too much, would you be able to clarify on this overlap?

Comment: If you just use Alt-Z for x-ray mode and Ctrl-3 on the numpad for side view, you can see that there's one vertex in the middle of the shoulder area which is a lot higher than the others. Select it and change to front view and move it down and outwards to improve the topology a bit which should help with the shading. There's also one vertex at the heel of the feet which doesn't seem to be in the correct place! :^)